# Oracle JDBC Template extremely slow with parameters

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have a problem, I use JDBCTemplate in SpringBoot with oracle 19c and using this following query:

```sql
SELECT
    CLIENT_EXTRA_INFO.CLIENT_NUMBER,
    CLIENT_EXTRA_INFO.FULL_NAME,
FROM
     CONTRACT
        JOIN CLIENT_EXTRA_INFO on (CONTRACT.CLIENTID = CLIENT_EXTRA_INFO.ID)
WHERE
    CLIENT_EXTRA_INFO.MBPHONE = '0343423223'
  and CONTRACT.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
  and CONTRACT.FLAG IN ('2', '5') FETCH  FIRST  10 ROWS ONLY;
```

It run fast on console, about 300ms, but when add use it with JDBC and add parameter to phone number:

```java
@Override
    public ResponsePagingDTO<RetailCustomerDTO> getDuplicateRetailCustomerWithPhoneNumber(DuplicatePhoneNumberRequest request) {
        MapSqlParameterSource mapSqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("phone", request.getPhoneNumber());
        mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("row", request.getSize());
        String sql ="SELECT\n" +
        "    CLIENT_EXTRA_INFO.CLIENT_NUMBER,\n" +
        "    CLIENT_EXTRA_INFO.FULL_NAME,\n" +
        "FROM\n" +
        "     CONTRACT\n" +
        "        JOIN CLIENT_EXTRA_INFO on (CONTRACT.CLIENTID = CLIENT_EXTRA_INFO.ID)\n" +
        "WHERE\n" +
        "    CLIENT_EXTRA_INFO.MBPHONE = :phone\n" +
        "  and CONTRACT.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'\n" +
        "  and CONTRACT.FLAG IN ('2', '5') FETCH  FIRST  :row ROWS ONLY";


        ResponsePagingDTO<RetailCustomerDTO> responsePagingDTO = new ResponsePagingDTO<>();


        List<RetailCustomerDTO> retailCustomerDTOS = new ArrayList<>();
        pulseOpsTemplateJdbc.query(sql, mapSqlParameterSource, (result -> {
            RetailCustomerDTO retailCustomer = new RetailCustomerDTO();
            retailCustomer.setClientNumber(result.getString(ClientConstant.CLIENT_NUM));
            retailCustomer.setFullName(result.getString(ClientConstant.FULL_NAME));
            retailCustomer.setPhoneNumber(request.getPhoneNumber());
            retailCustomerDTOS.add(retailCustomer);
        }));
        responsePagingDTO.setData(retailCustomerDTOS);
        return responsePagingDTO;
    }
}
```

The performance is very low, around 7 min to response compared to run it in console (300ms). Total data is about 80 million records, I have tried many solutions but none of them improve performance, all column in where statement have been indexed.

Have anyone got any solution for this problem? Many thanks to you guys.

Comment: Your code looks like you have hard-coded the phone number into the query (line 13) rather than using the parameter you defined. You don't have any parameters in your SQL at all - you should look to fix that first.

Comment: Sorry that my mistake when copy the code while I testing without parameter. In my code there are parameter for phone number

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using materialized view and create scheduler to reset it every 24h, the query now much faster about 800ms.